# Eclipse CDT and External Library (VTK)

Tags: eclipse, linker, vtk

I am trying to use an external library (VTK) within Eclipse CDT on Windows7.
I have tried to add include directory (-I) and lib directory (-L) to the project options.
I am not sure about DLL files.

```
g++ -LE:\VTK\VTKLibs\lib\vtk-5.4 -LE:\HSimulator\New Folder 
-o VTK_Cygwin.exe src\VTK_Cygwin.o 
-lvtkGraphics -lvtkftgl -lvtkjpeg -lvtkpng -lvtktiff -lvtkzlib -lvtkHybrid -lvtkmetaio 
-lvtkImaging -lvtkfreetype -lvtkCommon -lvtkalglib
```

However, I get the following error:

```
src\VTK_Cygwin.o: In function `~vtkSmartPointer':
include/vtkSmartPointer.h:27: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
```

I tried different ways but I can't figure out the problem.
Is there a way to track linking problem in Eclipse CDT?

Thanks